# Can I get Spring Validation errors in prehandle

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently have something similar to this in all of my endpoints in my spring app.

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I would like to move this to a http interceptor so that I only need it in one place. However, I cannot figure out how to get all of the errors from the binding result in `preHandle`.

How would I get validation errors in preHandle, or some other time before it starts the actual route?

Comment: Which Spring version you are using, you can capture any exception in ControllerAdvice at one place, you can check example at [Exception Spring Handler](https://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver)

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what I think you're looking for is to not include BindingResult as a method parameter. Given no BindingResult is included as a method argument Spring will throw a BindException exception. You can define an ExceptionHandler, generally I've placed these within a @ControllerAdvice, to handle the exception as needed. Below is some sample code

Controller

```
@PostMapping
public SomeReturnObject someMethod(@Valid SomeCommand command) {
    // logic - no longer contains checks for binding result errors 
}
```

As part of ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ApplicationControllerAdvice {

    ....

    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    protected SomeResponse handleBindException(BindException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: So if I just include it on the basepath than it will auto intercept all binding exceptions? Or do I have to configure ControllerAdvice somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say include it on the basepath but I did update my example of the controller advice. Essentially it just comes down to annotation a class with @ControllerAdvice